# Create a map using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have document with fields:
`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`

Currently if I iterate over the collection with such documents, I get the full dictionary as output. Is there a way to get output in a key value pair with value of b as key and rest of the information as value, for example:

Suppose, there is a document: `{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}`
then output should be:

```
{2:{'a':1,'c':3,'d':4}}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that value will be same ?

Comment: @Lafada your edit changed OP's question and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach like this,

```
for itm in db.collection.find():
    print {itm.pop('b'): itm}
```

Here collection is the name of  your collection in the database. If you iterate over the pymongo cursor object you will get `dict` type object which you can modify like normal python dict.